# jquery serialize returns an empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a problem when using the `serialize()` jQuery function:

```
<form role="form" id="enter-image-detail-form" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="image-name" placeholder="Enter image name" value="test">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success btn-block">Save</button>
</form>
```

```js
$('body').on('submit', '#enter-image-detail-form', function(e){
  console.log( $(this).serialize() );
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

It returns an empty string. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're right, my bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add name attribute for form elements since [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method generates form elements which has name attribute.

```
<input name="image-name" type="text" class="form-control" id="image-name" placeholder="Enter image name" value="test">
<!--   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                  --->
```

From [docs](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) :

> For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the help!